# NativeScript Angular BottomSheet

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, bottom-sheet

Hello everyone good day,
I have a running angular project that uses the [angular material bottomsheet component](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/examples)

my question now is; how to implement same behaviour in nativescript angular.

Thank you for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [nativescript-cfalert-dialog](https://github.com/shiv19/nativescript-cfalert-dialog)

```
tns plugin add nativescript-cfalert-dialog
```

and set the `dialogStyle` to `CFAlertStyle.BOTTOM_SHEET`

Comment: Thank you very much. Just what i needed
But is there anyway i can achieve the open from component like [this](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview#configuring-bottom-sheet-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-)

Comment: Later found out that the api doesnt do what i needed

Answer (score 0):

```
"nativescript-material-bottomsheet": "2.5.4", //package.json

import { MenuBottomSheet } from "../bottomsheet/menu.bottomsheet";
import { BottomSheetOptions, BottomSheetService } from 'nativescript-material-bottomsheet/angular';


fabTap(){
        const options: BottomSheetOptions = {
            viewContainerRef: this.containerRef,
            context: ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Twitter'],
        };

        this.bottomSheet.show(MenuBottomSheet, options).subscribe(result => {
            console.log('Option selected:', result);
        });
    }
```

It acts as a modal in nativescript